# Cannot Connect to the real www.google.com

Tags: windows, google-chrome, networking, connection

I have received this message that I'm not able to connect to the real Google site when I use Chrome as my Browser. I have tried to solved the problem by

1. Checking my time zone. (because of SSL Credential)
2. Checking my Browser Proxy.
3. resetting my setting to default
4. clearing all caches and cookies
5. Flushing DNS

but nothing happens.

when I checked the browser in safe mode I saw that it could connect to google.
I think there is an application that cause the problem.

I would appreciate if you help me to find the solution and tell me how I can check my connection in the Application layer of OSI model.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a [related thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/5-Bf0o6YxgM) in a Google Chrome forum.

I think that the technology responsible for catching this is [HTTP Strict Transport Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security);

It looks like one of your extensions is intercepting SSL traffic and, in your case, that looks like BitDefender.

I would stop using BitDefender, but if you want to continue using it you could either look for a setting that stops it from intercepting SSL traffic or contact their support.

Comment: Thanks. it does work for me.I just disable SSL Scan on my bitdefender.  would you please tell me is there any software that tell me where the congestion is when I'm facing with this kind of problem(something same as trace route in network but in application layer).

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.  I wish I could help you more, but I really don't know anything about the OSI model.  I think that's something they teach in a formal computer science curriculum, but I'm entirely self-taught.  I was only able to help answer your question because I listen to a security podcast in which they discussed this exact problem recently.  As I understand it, there's not really a path with SSL like there is with IP routing.  The browsers have a built-in list of trusted certificate authorities that they use to verify SSL signatures.

Answer (score 11):

Somehow, my computer was one year behind the actual time.
I adjusted to the correct time and the time zone.
I closed and open Google Chrome. Problem was fixed.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get past that just type in 'danger' in your browser. (just click on the window anywhere and type 'danger', you won't actually see the letters appear anywhere) it used to be proceed but that no longer works.

Comment: It seems this still works.

Answer (score 2):

This problem happens because your system datetime is wrong. Update your window datetime correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I am running WIn XP WITHOUT SP3 update and this solution worked for me when using Chrome.

http://www.technonsense.com/2014/04/chrome-ssl-error-solution/

In short, modify your Chrome shortcut used to access the browser by appending "-ignore-certificate-errors" (without quotes) in the target field (and after "...exe").

I hope this speeds you on your way!

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the actual time setting of the clock, using one of the Internet time providers. (You mentioned that you checked the time zone, but not the actual time). To do this, double-click clock, Change Date & Time, select Internet Time tab, then Change Settings, and synchronize with one of the providers listed there. If one doesn't work, try another.

Failing that, also try disabling any extensions that you have installed. Type the following into Chrome's address bar, and select the Extensions tab on the left:

```
chrome://extensions/
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is basically on older version of OS e.g. Windows-XP with SP-II. SHA-2 algorithm has been used to generate SSL certificates which is not in range of older version of OS.

There are two solutions for the problem as:

1. Upgrade the OS. Use another OS or upgrade existing one (with SP-III). or
2. Generate new SSL certificates with SHA-1 algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

the solution consists in activating a flag for ignoring errors caused by certificates,
does not ignore the certificate itself but only the consequent error,
that is obtained by launching the binary with a specific parameter,

for your own reference: http://www.technonsense.com/2014/04/chrome-ssl-error-solution/

the fix forces the override of the default behaviour about certificates error